# Why the following Regex expression is not working with list.files function in R Studio-Version(3.1.2)?

Tags: r

I am trying to use list.files(path = file_path , pattern = temp) to list files inside this folder and filter the required file using pattern. There is no error and file is also available inside that folder but still its returning character(0).

```
file_path <- "Z:\\files_R\\Results"
x <- "product-0121-2019"
temp <- sprintf("^%s(.*)test.xlsx$", x)

#i.e -->temp <- "^product-0121-2019(.*)test.xlsx$" 

files <- list.files(path =file_path,pattern = temp)
```

I expect the file name  as output to be stored in "files" which matches the pattern specified. But i am getting character(0)."product-0121-2019-e2-CAN-test.xlsx" this file is residing inside that folder but still i am not getting the correct output.

is there anything wrong in my usage of functions or syntax in R?

Thanks in Advance!!

i tried using

```
temp <- sprintf("^[%s](.*)test.xlsx$", x)
```

[%s] instead of %s, for some rows this is working fine but for some rows i am getting the following error **"Error in list.files(path = file_name, pattern = temp) : invalid 'pattern' regular expression"**

Comment: Can you try `list.files("Z:\\files_R\\Results\\",pattern = "^product-0121-2019.*test\\.xlsx$")`

Comment: Yes I tried but the same results. x value is dynamic and i should use a variable next to caret(^) symbol.

Comment: sprintf("^%s(.*)test.xlsx$", x) --> using sprintf will it give a valid regular expression?

Comment: Have you tried just `"%s.*test\\.xlsx$` and do you have any characters that could be an issue in other values of x if that is being set dynamically. You might want to try `/` in place of `\\\` maybe those are being 'unixised' internally somewhere?

Comment: yes...Actually for x in some of the dynamic values "()" is present, because of this the error was coming like "Invalid Regular Expression". When I tried using `\\(` and `\\)` instead of "(" and ")", its working fine now.                                                                       Thanks for the hint Richard and Thank you all for the suggestions.